# Can Spark rand() return the value 1.0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Checking Spark documentation I have found that:

- calling pyspark.sql.functions.rand [might return 1.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rand) ([0.0, 1.0])
- SQL rand() [will not return 1.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rand) ([0, 1)).

Is this a mistake in documentation, or is behavior actually different depending on where the call comes from?